# Doctor Who episode where the Doctor meets a Time Lord who mentions his real/nick name

Tags: doctor-who, episode-identification

I remember a Tom Baker (4th Doctor) episode of *Doctor Who* where he met a Time Lord, possibly an old friend from childhood, who at some point mentioned his real name or at least a nickname. Does anyone know something about this? The episode or the name?

Comment: See also http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/3637/what-is-the-etymology-of-doctor-who, where "Thete", or "Theta Sigma" is mentioned, and http://tardis.wikia.com/wiki/Aliases_of_the_Doctor where there is a lot of detail about the Doctor's names.

Comment: When Tom Baker was the Dr., he was introduced by an official greeter at an official function/gathering with his real name. It may have been on Gallifrey and I believe he had a companion with him.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was a nickname, from his university days.

In *[The Armageddon Factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Armageddon_Factor)*, the nick name was: **Thete**.

> DRAX: Hello, Theet. How you been, boy?
>
> DOCTOR: What?
>
> DRAX: It is Theet, innit? Theta Sigma? Yeah, 'course it is. Remember me, ay?

Comment: Short for Theta Sigma.

Answer (score 0):

I remember that he met a fellow Gallifreyan n in a cave system underneath some city possibly on Gallifrey itself. They used to be in school together and they talked about this though it seemed obvious to me that The Doctor did not particularly like this person. The person he met then called him by his real name. The name was clearly spoken though I can not remember what it was.

I seem to remember that Tom Baker gave him a nasty look then said something quite stern about how he had earned his title "The Doctor" and that is how he should be addressed. I also remember that it seemed to be forbidden to use his real name.

The childhood acquaintance obviously didn't know he had earned the title and it was felt that he had done quite the faux pas in dishonoring by saying his real name out loud.

It made me believe that there was a ranking system and that the Doctor regarded this person as beneath him because he never passed. The title the Doctor, might be a Knight, baron or even a Duke, while his school fellow was only slightly higher than a servant. This fellow obviously felt inferior to the Doctor for the same reason.

And no, I don't know the episode number, I only discovered this page by looking for this same answer.

Note: I was very young when I saw this episode well over 30 years ago(?), so forgive me if my memory of it is incorrect

Comment: You're describing "The Armageddon Factor," the episode referenced in [Richard's answer above](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/6052/31051). However, it wasn't the Doctor's real name; it was a university nickname. "Doctor" is referred to as its academic usage; the Doctor says that he "earned his Doctorate"

Comment: hmm found it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=u5Y2anevL2o

Comment: now that you've found the episode clip, you should edit your answer to include the actual quote as well as the cilp and information about the episode.