# Does the Doctor have a name?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In Voyager an emergency medical protocol hologram becomes the primary medical officer, developing he ability to sing, a personality and even friends.

Does he ever get a name which he stuck with? What was the reason he stuck with that name above any others he was given or took?

Comment: [Memory Alpha answers this directly.](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Doctor#Names)

Comment: In addition to being general reference, this is a list question.

Comment: When I read the title, I thought it was referring to [the oldest question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/10660/the-oldest-question). :)

Comment: @bitmask I didn't think he'd have more than one. I'm not after a list.

Comment: @jwodder I think it hits the second box on the [flow chart](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/02/are-some-questions-too-simple/) *...in need of improvement*. I have no idea which of those is his true name, under what circumstances they might be used etc. I'm looking for expert-level help in understanding those names better.

Comment: @Pureferret: The first [hit I get](http://www.google.de/search?q=star+trek+voyager+Does+the+Doctor+have+a+name) gets me to the Wikipedia article. Where I see without scrolling a section *Name* in the TOC. If I click on it gives me a [paragraph with all relevant information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doctor_(Star_Trek:_Voyager)#Name). How is that hard to parse or slow to load? Also each name has it's own reference (most of the time with a link to the appropriate episode discussed on Wikipedia).

Comment: it took you thirty-three years to come up with 'Joe'?

Comment: @bitmask it's not slow to load. The exposition you give in your answer is what I'm after though, and that's not in the wikipedia article. The information in Memory Alpha requires me to hunt through episodes to find the sort of exposition you give. That's not 'easy to parse'

Comment: @Pureferret: Then maybe it's my encyclopaedic knowledge of VOY, that made me think it was trivial ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you insist in a single name, he actually accepted for himself (not a role he played for the sake of beings who wouldn't have grasped "The Doctor"), that would be

> Schmullus

It was given to him by Denara Pel, but he later stopped using it (and asked to be called "The Doctor") because the name remembered him of her (which apparently was *too painful*).

However, you could still argue that *Joe* is his actual name, but from the past-*Endgame* perspective he never chose that name in the first place (history rewritten, and so on).

Answer (score 1):

Kinda yes, in the final episode, we see an alternate future where the Voyager crew eventually made it home.  In this future, he picked the *extremely creative* name "Joe".

Comment: So nothing in the 'normal' timeline?

Comment: Nothing that stuck.